# How to get rid of Errors after moving Laravel Project in sub Directory

Tags: php, laravel, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have created a PHP project by using `Laravel Framework`. Everything is working fine on my local server. This is my `localhost url`

`localhost/projectName/public`

The above mentioned Url is perfectly opening the Login page, but when i movie this site to my website, it starts giving me error messages.

This is my Website path for this project.

`www.WebsiteName.com/ProjectName/public/`

The login page is opening perfectly fine, but many inner pages are giving error messages.

i.e:`No Query Result for Model`

Also when i try to move the `Laravel Project` folder into the `sub folder` in my `local server`. It starts giving me many error messages.

When I try to open the following page, it opens the login page, but inner pages do not open and give many error messages.

`localhost/MainFolder/ProjectFolder/public`

`Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException`

`Open: D:\xampp\htdocs\MainFolder\ProjectFolder\bootstrap\compiled.php`

Kindly guide me how to get rid of these `URL` Problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Path in url as mentioned in th Laravel  Documentation for your Links as you need . check out this link http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#paths

```
app_path();base_path();public_path();storage_path();
```